# How does Visual Studio 2012 Web Essentials offer LESS support?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, less, web-essentials

I wanted to know if Web Essentials just includes some library to compile LESS, like dotLess, in the bundle, or if it is itself a compiler for LESS, along with other utilities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It just includes the [LESS](http://lesscss.org) compiler.
(More specifically WE2012 uses [less.js script run in WSH](https://github.com/madskristensen/WebEssentials2012/blob/8459a596595ef494084f6e2c4c49a0d63e0f428d/EditorExtensions/EditorExtensions.csproj#L563))

Comment: Thank you. Just as a confirmation, less.js compiles less files on the server right? And then serves the corresponding css files?

Comment: Not exactly. Less.js is just a script (one of [these](https://github.com/less/less.js/tree/master/dist)), it runs just wherever you run it (a server, a browser or a local machine). The script only compiles less files to css files but what happens to the compiled css files next is out of its authority. (Except the in-browser usage when compiled css is just unlined into corresponding html).

Answer (score 0):

[Mads Kristensen](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/site/search?f%5B0%5D.Type=User&f%5B0%5D.Value=Mads%20Kristensen) says:

> We're slowly moving over to use NodeJS for compiling LESS and
>   CoffeeScript, but only in WE 2013. Right now, only LESS uses NodeJS
>   for compiling, but we're moving CoffeeScript to nodejs soon as well